# phpbb adding a link to header

Tags: html, phpbb3, forums

I'm using phpBB 3 with SE_Gamer style ( http://www.awesomestyles.com/phpbb3-styles/view/se-gamer ). I want to add a link to my main site (mysite.com) right next to "Board / FAQ / Members (if logged in) / Search" at the top left of the site. The link should read "Go to EFN Wiki" and the link should be http://www.mysite.com.

Below is the overall_header.html. Please indicate what changes I need to implement as I'm very new to programming!

Thanks in advance!!

```
<!-- INCLUDE se_gamer_config.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="{S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}" lang="{S_USER_LANG}" xml:lang="{S_USER_LANG}">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset={S_CONTENT_ENCODING}" />
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="{S_USER_LANG}" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name="resource-type" content="document" />
<meta name="distribution" content="global" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
{META}
<title>{SITENAME} &bull; <!-- IF S_IN_MCP -->{L_MCP} &bull; <!-- ELSEIF S_IN_UCP -->{L_UCP} &bull; <!-- ENDIF -->{PAGE_TITLE}</title>

<!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_OVERALL --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {SITENAME}" href="{U_FEED}" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_NEWS --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_FEED_NEWS}" href="{U_FEED}?mode=news" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_FORUMS --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_ALL_FORUMS}" href="{U_FEED}?mode=forums" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_TOPICS --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_FEED_TOPICS_NEW}" href="{U_FEED}?mode=topics" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_TOPICS_ACTIVE --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_FEED_TOPICS_ACTIVE}" href="{U_FEED}?mode=topics_active" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_FORUM and S_FORUM_ID --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_FORUM} - {FORUM_NAME}" href="{U_FEED}?f={S_FORUM_ID}" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_TOPIC and S_TOPIC_ID --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_TOPIC} - {TOPIC_TITLE}" href="{U_FEED}?f={S_FORUM_ID}&amp;t={S_TOPIC_ID}" /><!-- ENDIF -->
<!-- ENDIF -->

<!--
    phpBB style name: *SE Gamer: Light
    Based on style:   prosilver (this is the default phpBB3 style)
    Original author:  Tom Beddard ( http://www.subblue.com/ )
    Modified by:      Christian Bullock     
-->

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var jump_page = '{LA_JUMP_PAGE}:';
    var on_page = '{ON_PAGE}';
    var per_page = '{PER_PAGE}';
    var base_url = '{A_BASE_URL}';
    var style_cookie = 'phpBBstyle';
    var style_cookie_settings = '{A_COOKIE_SETTINGS}';
    var onload_functions = new Array();
    var onunload_functions = new Array();

    <!-- IF S_USER_PM_POPUP and S_NEW_PM -->
        var url = '{UA_POPUP_PM}';
        window.open(url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&'), '_phpbbprivmsg', 'height=225,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes, width=400');
    <!-- ENDIF -->

    /**
    * Find a member
    */
    function find_username(url)
    {
        popup(url, 760, 570, '_usersearch');
        return false;
    }

    /**
    * New function for handling multiple calls to window.onload and window.unload by pentapenguin
    */
    window.onload = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < onload_functions.length; i++)
        {
            eval(onload_functions[i]);
        }
    };

    window.onunload = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < onunload_functions.length; i++)
        {
            eval(onunload_functions[i]);
        }
    };

// ]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{T_SUPER_TEMPLATE_PATH}/forum_fn.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{T_TEMPLATE_PATH}/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{T_TEMPLATE_PATH}/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<!-- IF $COLLAPSIBLE_CATEGORIES == 'on' -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{T_TEMPLATE_PATH}/jquery.collapse.js"></script>
<!-- ENDIF -->



<link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" title="printonly" />
<link href="{T_STYLESHEET_LINK}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

<link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/normal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="A" />
<link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/medium.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="A+" />
<link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/large.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="A++" />

<!-- IF S_CONTENT_DIRECTION eq 'rtl' -->
    <link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/bidi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<!-- ENDIF -->

</head>

<body id="phpbb" class="section-{SCRIPT_NAME} {S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}">

<div id="wrap" style="width: {$BOARD_WIDTH}; max-width: {$MAX_BOARD_WIDTH};">
    <div class="border-left">
    <div class="border-right">
    <div class="border-top">
    <div class="border-top-left">
    <div class="border-top-right">
        <div class="inside" style="direction: {S_CONTENT_DIRECTION};">
            <a id="top" name="top" accesskey="t"></a>
                <div class="headerbar">
                    <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>
                        <div style="text-align: <!-- IF $LOGO_POSITION == 'left' -->left<!-- ELSEIF $LOGO_POSITION == 'center' -->center<!-- ELSEIF $LOGO_POSITION == 'right' -->right<!-- ELSE -->left<!-- ENDIF -->;">
                            <!-- IF $LOGO_TYPE == 'logo' -->
                                <a href="{U_INDEX}" title="{L_INDEX}" id="logo">{SITE_LOGO_IMG}</a>
                            <!-- ELSE -->
                                <h1 class="logotext"><span>*</span>{SITENAME}</h1>
                            <!-- ENDIF -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="nav">
                    <div class="fl">
                        <ul>
                            <li<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'index' --> class="current"<!-- ENDIF -->><a href="{U_INDEX}">{L_INDEX}</a></li>
                            <li<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'faq' --> class="current"<!-- ENDIF -->><a href="{U_FAQ}">{L_FAQ}</a></li>
                            <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_MEMBERLIST -->
                                <li<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'memberlist' --> class="current"<!-- ENDIF -->><a href="{U_MEMBERLIST}">{L_MEMBERLIST}</a></li>
                            <!-- ENDIF -->
                            <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_SEARCH -->
                                <li<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'search' --> class="current"<!-- ENDIF -->><a href="{U_SEARCH}">{L_SEARCH}</a></li>
                            <!-- ENDIF -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fr">
                        <ul>
                            <!-- <li>
                                <a href="#">{L_DISPLAY} {L_OPTIONS} <span class="droptip"></span></a>
                                <div class="optionspanel">
                                    User options coming in future release.
                                </div>
                            </li> -->
                            <!-- IF $SHOW_SEARCH_IN_NAV == 'yes' -->
                                <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_SEARCH and not S_IN_SEARCH -->
                                    <li>
                                        <form action="{U_SEARCH}" method="get" id="search">
                                            <input name="keywords" type="text" maxlength="128" title="{L_SEARCH_KEYWORDS}" class="quicksearch" value="<!-- IF SEARCH_WORDS-->{SEARCH_WORDS}<!-- ELSE -->{L_SEARCH_MINI}<!-- ENDIF -->" onclick="if(this.value=='{LA_SEARCH_MINI}')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='{LA_SEARCH_MINI}';" />
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                <!-- ENDIF -->                              
                            <!-- ENDIF -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cb"></div>
                    <span class="nav-corners-bottom"><span></span></span>
                </div>

                <br />    

                <!-- IF $SIDEBAR_ON_PAGES == 'global'  or ($SIDEBAR_ON_PAGES == 'index' and SCRIPT_NAME eq 'index') -->
                <div class="sidebarwrapper">
                    <!-- IF $SIDEBARS == 'left' -->
                        <div class="fixedfluid-sidebar">
                            <!-- INCLUDE sidebar_left.html -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="fixedfluid-content">
                    <!-- ELSEIF $SIDEBARS == 'right' -->
                        <div class="fluidfixed-sidebar">
                            <!-- INCLUDE sidebar_right.html -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="fluidfixed-content">
                    <!-- ELSEIF $SIDEBARS == 'both' -->
                        <div class="fixedfluidfixed-left">
                            <!-- INCLUDE sidebar_left.html -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="fixedfluidfixed-content">
                    <!-- ENDIF -->
                <!-- ENDIF -->

                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>

                    <ul class="linklist navlinks">
                        <li><i class="icon-home"></i> <a href="{U_INDEX}" accesskey="h">{L_INDEX}</a> <!-- BEGIN navlinks --> <strong>&#8249;</strong> <a href="{navlinks.U_VIEW_FORUM}">{navlinks.FORUM_NAME}</a><!-- END navlinks --></li>

                        <!-- IF U_EMAIL_TOPIC --><li class="rightside"><a href="{U_EMAIL_TOPIC}" title="{L_EMAIL_TOPIC}" class="sendemail">{L_EMAIL_TOPIC}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                        <!-- IF U_EMAIL_PM --><li class="rightside"><a href="{U_EMAIL_PM}" title="{L_EMAIL_PM}" class="sendemail">{L_EMAIL_PM}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                        <!-- IF U_PRINT_TOPIC --><li class="rightside"><a href="{U_PRINT_TOPIC}" title="{L_PRINT_TOPIC}" accesskey="p" class="print">{L_PRINT_TOPIC}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                        <!-- IF U_PRINT_PM --><li class="rightside"><a href="{U_PRINT_PM}" title="{L_PRINT_PM}" accesskey="p" class="print">{L_PRINT_PM}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                    </ul>

                    <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT and S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->
                    <ul class="linklist leftside">
                        <li><i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                            <a href="{U_PROFILE}" title="{L_PROFILE}" accesskey="e">{L_PROFILE}</a>
                                <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_PM -->&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> <a href="{U_PRIVATEMSGS}">{PRIVATE_MESSAGE_INFO}</a><!-- ENDIF -->
                            <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_SEARCH --> &nbsp;&bull;
                            &nbsp;<a href="{U_SEARCH_SELF}">{L_SEARCH_SELF}</a>
                            <!-- ENDIF -->
                            <!-- IF U_RESTORE_PERMISSIONS --> &bull;
                            <a href="{U_RESTORE_PERMISSIONS}">{L_RESTORE_PERMISSIONS}</a>
                            <!-- ENDIF -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- ENDIF -->

                    <ul class="linklist rightside">
                        <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT -->
                            <!-- IF not S_USER_LOGGED_IN and S_REGISTER_ENABLED and not (S_SHOW_COPPA or S_REGISTRATION) --><li><i class="icon-plus"></i> <a href="{U_REGISTER}">{L_REGISTER}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                            <li><i class="icon-off"></i> <a href="{U_LOGIN_LOGOUT}" title="{L_LOGIN_LOGOUT}" accesskey="x">{L_LOGIN_LOGOUT}</a></li>
                        <!-- ENDIF -->
                    </ul>

                    <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
                </div>

            <a name="start_here"></a>
            <div id="page-body">

                <!-- IF S_BOARD_DISABLED and S_USER_LOGGED_IN and (U_MCP or U_ACP) -->
                <div id="information" class="rules">
                    <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>
                        <strong>{L_INFORMATION}:</strong> {L_BOARD_DISABLED}
                    <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
                </div>
                <!-- ENDIF -->
```

Answer (score 0):

find:

```
<li<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'index' --> class="current"<!-- ENDIF -->><a href="{U_INDEX}">{L_INDEX}</a></li>
```

add on a blank line BEFORE:

```
<li><a href="http://www.mysite.com">Go to EFN Wiki</a></li>
```

If your wiki pages are inside phpBB then you can use instead:

```
<li<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'xxxx' --> class="current"<!-- ENDIF -->><a href="http://www.mysite.com">Go to EFN Wiki</a></li>
```

change the `xxxx` part to whatever the filename of your wiki index is, but without the `.php` extension.

Remember to back up the files before making any edits, that way if something doesn't work you can replace the broken files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However it doesn't seem to work... (I'm using th e first solution). In fact nothing happens at all. And I've cleared the cache multiple times.

Comment: Are you editing the files on the server or using the template editor in the ACP?

Comment: I'm editing the files on Notepad++ and I upload them directly to the server